# I am making an app in Python tkinter. Thing is that I cannot figure out how to put what I have in the first tab to all the remaining notebook tabs

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

1. I am making an app in Python tkinter. Thing is that I cannot figure out how to put what I have in the first tab to all the remaining notebook tabs.
2. What are the steps needed to accomplish this task.
   How much detail do you need stackoverflow "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details". There is nothing more I need to add here. I am making a simple program that requires a simple answer.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import END, ANCHOR

# Define fonts and colors
text_color = "#fffacd"
menu_color = "#6c769b"
root_color = "#6c899a"
button_color = "#6c898a"
my_font = ("Times New Roman", 10)

# Define Window
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("IT2Go NotePad")
root.iconbitmap("pad.ico")
root.geometry('500x500')
root.config(bg=root_color)
# root.resizable(0, 0)

it2goNotebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
it2goNotebook.pack(pady=15)

# Create frame
docks = Frame(it2goNotebook, width=500, height=500, bg=root_color)
kbcombo = Frame(it2goNotebook, width=500, height=500, bg=menu_color)
monitors = Frame(it2goNotebook, width=500, height=500, bg=root_color)
webcams = Frame(it2goNotebook, width=500, height=500, bg=menu_color)
headsets = Frame(it2goNotebook, width=500, height=500, bg=root_color)
pucks = Frame(it2goNotebook, width=500, height=500, bg=menu_color)

docks.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
kbcombo.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
monitors.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
webcams.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
headsets.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
pucks.pack(fill="both", expand=1)

it2goNotebook.add(docks, text="Docks")
it2goNotebook.add(kbcombo, text="KB Combo")
it2goNotebook.add(monitors, text="Monitors")
it2goNotebook.add(webcams, text="Webcams")
it2goNotebook.add(headsets, text="Headsets")
it2goNotebook.add(pucks, text="Pucks")

# Define functions
def add_name():
    """Add name to list box"""
    my_listbox.insert(END, list_entry.get())
    list_entry.delete(0, END)

def remove_item():
    """Remove the selected (ANCHOR) item from the listbox"""
    my_listbox.delete(ANCHOR)

def save_list():
    """Save file to Text File"""
    with open("docklist.txt", 'w') as f:
        # listbox.get() returns a tuple
        list_tuple = my_listbox.get(0, END)
        for item in list_tuple:
        # Take proper precautions to include only on \n for formatting purposes
            if item.endswith("\n"):
                f.write(item)
            else:
                f.write(item + "\n")

def open_list():
    """Open list if there is one upon starting"""
    try:
        with open("docklist.txt", 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                my_listbox.insert(END, line)
    except:
        return

# Define Docks Layout
input_frame = tkinter.Frame(docks, bg=menu_color)
output_frame = tkinter.Frame(docks, bg=menu_color)
button_frame = tkinter.Frame(docks, bg=button_color)
input_frame.pack()
button_frame.pack()

# Input Docks layout
list_entry = tkinter.Entry(input_frame, width=41, borderwidth=5, font=my_font)
list_add_button = tkinter.Button(input_frame, text="Add A Name", borderwidth=5, font=my_font, bg=button_color, command=add_name)
output_frame.pack()
list_entry.grid(row=0, column=0)
list_add_button.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=2, pady=5, ipadx=5)

# Output Docks layout
my_scrollbar = tkinter.Scrollbar(output_frame)
my_listbox = tkinter.Listbox(output_frame, height=15, width=60, borderwidth=3, font=my_font, yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar.set)
# Link scrollbar to listbox
my_scrollbar.config(command=my_listbox.yview)
my_listbox.grid(row=0, column=0)
my_scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=NS)

# Button Docks Layout
remove_item_button = tkinter.Button(button_frame, text="Remove Name", borderwidth=5, font=my_font, bg=button_color, command=remove_item)
save_button = tkinter.Button(button_frame, text="Save", borderwidth=5, font=my_font, bg=button_color, command=save_list)
quit_button = tkinter.Button(button_frame, text="Quit", borderwidth=5, font=my_font, bg=button_color, command=root.destroy)
remove_item_button.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5)
save_button.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=30)
quit_button.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=30)

# Open the previous list if available
open_list()

# Run the root windows's main loop
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

Make a list of all tabs:

```
tabs = [docks, kbcombo, monitors, webcams, headsets, pucks]
```

Now you should just be able to put the rest in a for-loop:

```
for tab in tabs:
# Define Docks Layout
    input_frame = tkinter.Frame(tab, bg=menu_color)
    output_frame = tkinter.Frame(tab, bg=menu_color)
    button_frame = tkinter.Frame(tab, bg=button_color)
    input_frame.pack()
    button_frame.pack()

    # Input Docks layout
    list_entry = tkinter.Entry(input_frame, width=41, borderwidth=5, font=my_font)
    list_add_button = tkinter.Button(input_frame, text="Add A Name", borderwidth=5, font=my_font, bg=button_color, command=add_name)
    output_frame.pack()
    list_entry.grid(row=0, column=0)
    list_add_button.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=2, pady=5, ipadx=5)

    # Output Docks layout
    my_scrollbar = tkinter.Scrollbar(output_frame)
    my_listbox = tkinter.Listbox(output_frame, height=15, width=60, borderwidth=3, font=my_font, yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar.set)
    # Link scrollbar to listbox
    my_scrollbar.config(command=my_listbox.yview)
    my_listbox.grid(row=0, column=0)
    my_scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=NS)

    # Button Docks Layout
    remove_item_button = tkinter.Button(button_frame, text="Remove Name", borderwidth=5, font=my_font, bg=button_color, command=remove_item)
    save_button = tkinter.Button(button_frame, text="Save", borderwidth=5, font=my_font, bg=button_color, command=save_list)
    quit_button = tkinter.Button(button_frame, text="Quit", borderwidth=5, font=my_font, bg=button_color, command=root.destroy)
    remove_item_button.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5)
    save_button.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=30)
    quit_button.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=30)
```

Keep in mind that this removes the functionality of some of your app. You will need to update the functions to accept arguments (and then call them with the appropriate arguments), because objects such as `my_listbox` do not exist outside of the scope of the for-loop iteration. Here is one example:

```
def add_name(listbox, list_entry):
    """Add name to list box"""
    listbox.insert(END, list_entry.get())
    list_entry.delete(0, END)
```

You will need to rework your functions to behave like this. Also, make sure you create different files for each tab, so the lists don't all write over each other. This can also be done by passing the correct file name to a function.

Comment: Wow thanks. I appreciate your assistance. Good now I have a direction

Comment: That seemed to work until I tried to execute add_name command by using that button:
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: add_name() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'listbox' and 'list_entry'

Comment: # Define functions
def add_name(listbox, list_entry):
    """Add name to list box"""
    listbox.insert(END, list_entry.get())
    list_entry.delete(0, END)

Comment: yeah, you have to add parameters to all of the function calls with the correct Listbox/Entry. I just didn't do that so you could try to figure it out.

Comment: I took out the For Loop out and wrote it long hand with 440 lines of code. The natives where getting restless and I had to do something.

Comment: I could not figure it out... =\

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure it out....so I did it without the For Loop:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import END, ANCHOR

# Define fonts and colors
text_color = "#fffacd"
menu_color = "#6c769b"
root_color = "#6c899a"
button_color = "#6c898a"
my_font = ("Times New Roman", 10)

# Define Window
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("IT2Go NotePad")
root.iconbitmap("pad.ico")
root.geometry('500x500')
root.config(bg=root_color)
# root.resizable(0, 0)

it2goNotebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
it2goNotebook.pack(pady=15)

# Create frame
docks = Frame(it2goNotebook, width=500, height=500, bg=root_color)
kbcombo = Frame(it2goNotebook, width=500, height=500, bg=menu_color)
monitors = Frame(it2goNotebook, width=500, height=500, bg=root_color)
webcams = Frame(it2goNotebook, width=500, height=500, bg=menu_color)
headsets = Frame(it2goNotebook, width=500, height=500, bg=root_color)
pucks = Frame(it2goNotebook, width=500, height=500, bg=menu_color)

docks.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
kbcombo.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
monitors.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
webcams.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
headsets.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
pucks.pack(fill="both", expand=1)

it2goNotebook.add(docks, text="Docks")
it2goNotebook.add(kbcombo, text="KB Combo")
it2goNotebook.add(monitors, text="Monitors")
it2goNotebook.add(webcams, text="Webcams")
it2goNotebook.add(headsets, text="Headsets")
it2goNotebook.add(pucks, text="Pucks")

# Define functions
def add_name1():
    """Add name to list box"""
    my_listbox1.insert(END, list_entry1.get())
    list_entry1.delete(0, END)


def add_name2():
    """Add name to list box"""
    my_listbox2.insert(END, list_entry2.get())
    list_entry2.delete(0, END)


def add_name3():
    """Add name to list box"""
    my_listbox3.insert(END, list_entry3.get())
    list_entry3.delete(0, END)


def add_name4():
    """Add name to list box"""
    my_listbox4.insert(END, list_entry4.get())
    list_entry4.delete(0, END)


def add_name5():
    """Add name to list box"""
    my_listbox5.insert(END, list_entry5.get())
    list_entry5.delete(0, END)


def add_name6():
    """Add name to list box"""
    my_listbox6.insert(END, list_entry6.get())
    list_entry6.delete(0, END)


def remove_item1():
    """Remove the selected (ANCHOR) item from the listbox"""
    my_listbox1.delete(ANCHOR)


def remove_item2():
    """Remove the selected (ANCHOR) item from the listbox"""
    my_listbox2.delete(ANCHOR)


def remove_item3():
    """Remove the selected (ANCHOR) item from the listbox"""
    my_listbox3.delete(ANCHOR)


def remove_item4():
    """Remove the selected (ANCHOR) item from the listbox"""
    my_listbox4.delete(ANCHOR)


def remove_item5():
    """Remove the selected (ANCHOR) item from the listbox"""
    my_listbox5.delete(ANCHOR)


def remove_item6():
    """Remove the selected (ANCHOR) item from the listbox"""
    my_listbox6.delete(ANCHOR)


def save_list1():
    """Save file to Text File"""
    with open("docklst.txt", 'w') as f:
        # listbox.get() returns a tuple
        list_tuple = my_listbox1.get(0, END)
        for item in list_tuple:
        # Take proper precautions to include only on \n for formatting purposes
            if item.endswith("\n"):
                f.write(item)
            else:
                f.write(item + "\n")


def save_list2():
    """Save file to Text File"""
    with open("kbcombolst.txt", 'w') as f:
        # listbox.get() returns a tuple
        list_tuple = my_listbox2.get(0, END)
        for item in list_tuple:
        # Take proper precautions to include only on \n for formatting purposes
            if item.endswith("\n"):
                f.write(item)
            else:
                f.write(item + "\n")


def save_list3():
    """Save file to Text File"""
    with open("monitorslst.txt", 'w') as f:
        # listbox.get() returns a tuple
        list_tuple = my_listbox3.get(0, END)
        for item in list_tuple:
        # Take proper precautions to include only on \n for formatting purposes
            if item.endswith("\n"):
                f.write(item)
            else:
                f.write(item + "\n")


def save_list4():
    """Save file to Text File"""
    with open("webcamslst.txt", 'w') as f:
        # listbox.get() returns a tuple
        list_tuple = my_listbox4.get(0, END)
        for item in list_tuple:
        # Take proper precautions to include only on \n for formatting purposes
            if item.endswith("\n"):
                f.write(item)
            else:
                f.write(item + "\n")


def save_list5():
    """Save file to Text File"""
    with open("headsetslst.txt", 'w') as f:
        # listbox.get() returns a tuple
        list_tuple = my_listbox5.get(0, END)
        for item in list_tuple:
        # Take proper precautions to include only on \n for formatting purposes
            if item.endswith("\n"):
                f.write(item)
            else:
                f.write(item + "\n")


def save_list6():
    """Save file to Text File"""
    with open("puckslst.txt", 'w') as f:
        # listbox.get() returns a tuple
        list_tuple = my_listbox6.get(0, END)
        for item in list_tuple:
        # Take proper precautions to include only on \n for formatting purposes
            if item.endswith("\n"):
                f.write(item)
            else:
                f.write(item + "\n")

def open_list1():
    """Open list if there is one upon starting"""
    try:
        with open("docklist.txt", 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                my_listbox1.insert(END, line)
    except:
        return


def open_list2():
    """Open list if there is one upon starting"""
    try:
        with open("docklist.txt", 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                my_listbox2.insert(END, line)
    except:
        return


def open_list3():
    """Open list if there is one upon starting"""
    try:
        with open("docklist.txt", 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                my_listbox3.insert(END, line)
    except:
        return



def open_list4():
    """Open list if there is one upon starting"""
    try:
        with open("docklist.txt", 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                my_listbox4.insert(END, line)
    except:
        return


def open_list5():
    """Open list if there is one upon starting"""
    try:
        with open("docklist.txt", 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                my_listbox5.insert(END, line)
    except:
        return


def open_list6():
    """Open list if there is one upon starting"""
    try:
        with open("docklist.txt", 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                my_listbox6.insert(END, line)
    except:
        return


# Define Docks Layout
input_frame = tkinter.Frame(docks, bg=menu_color)
output_frame = tkinter.Frame(docks, bg=menu_color)
button_frame = tkinter.Frame(docks, bg=button_color)
input_frame.pack()
button_frame.pack()

# Input Docks layout
list_entry1 = tkinter.Entry(input_frame, width=41, borderwidth=5, font=my_font)
list_add_button1 = tkinter.Button(input_frame, text="Add A Name", borderwidth=5, font=my_font, bg=button_color, command=add_name1)
output_frame.pack()
list_entry1.grid(row=0, column=0)
list_add_button1.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=2, pady=5, ipadx=5)

# Output Docks layout
my_scrollbar1 = tkinter.Scrollbar(output_frame)
my_listbox1 = tkinter.Listbox(output_frame, height=15, width=60, borderwidth=3, font=my_font, yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar1.set)
# Link scrollbar to listbox
my_scrollbar1.config(command=my_listbox1.yview)
my_listbox1.grid(row=0, column=0)
my_scrollbar1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=NS)

# Button Docks Layout
remove_item_button1 = tkinter.Button(button_frame, text="Remove Name", borderwidth=5, font=my_font, bg=button_color, command=remove_item1)
save_button1 = tkinter.Button(button_frame, text="Save", borderwidth=5, font=my_font, bg=button_color, command=save_list1)
quit_button1 = tkinter.Button(button_frame, text="Quit", borderwidth=5, font=my_font, bg=button_color, command=root.destroy)
remove_item_button1.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5)
save_button1.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=30)
quit_button1.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=30)

# Define kbcombo Layout
input_frame = tkinter.Frame(kbcombo, bg=menu_color)
output_frame = tkinter.Frame(kbcombo, bg=menu_color)
button_frame = tkinter.Frame(kbcombo, bg=button_color)
input_frame.pack()
button_frame.pack()

# Input kbcombo layout
list_entry2 = tkinter.Entry(input_frame, width=41, borderwidth=5, font=my_font)
list_add_button2 = tkinter.Button(input_frame, text="Add A Name", borderwidth=5, font=my_font, bg=button_color, command=add_name2)
output_frame.pack()
list_entry2.grid(row=0, column=0)
list_add_button2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=2, pady=5, ipadx=5)

# Output kbcombo layout
my_scrollbar2 = tkinter.Scrollbar(output_frame)
my_listbox2 = tkinter.Listbox(output_frame, height=15, width=60, borderwidth=3, font=my_font, yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar2.set)
# Link scrollbar to listbox
my_scrollbar2.config(command=my_listbox2.yview)
my_listbox2.grid(row=0, column=0)
my_scrollbar2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=NS)

# Button kbcombo Layout
remove_item_button2 = tkinter.Button(button_frame, text="Remove Name", borderwidth=5, font=my_font, bg=button_color, command=remove_item2)
save_button2 = tkinter.Button(button_frame, text="Save", borderwidth=5, font=my_font, bg=button_color, command=save_list2)
quit_button2 = tkinter.Button(button_frame, text="Quit", borderwidth=5, font=my_font, bg=button_color, command=root.destroy)
remove_item_button2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5)
save_button2.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=30)
quit_button2.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=30)

# Define monitors Layout
input_frame = tkinter.Frame(monitors, bg=menu_color)
output_frame = tkinter.Frame(monitors, bg=menu_color)
button_frame = tkinter.Frame(monitors, bg=button_color)
input_frame.pack()
button_frame.pack()

# Input monitors layout
list_entry3 = tkinter.Entry(input_frame, width=41, borderwidth=5, font=my_font)
list_add_button3 = tkinter.Button(input_frame, text="Add A Name", borderwidth=5, font=my_font, bg=button_color, command=add_name3)
output_frame.pack()
list_entry3.grid(row=0, column=0)
list_add_button3.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=2, pady=5, ipadx=5)

# Output monitors layout
my_scrollbar3 = tkinter.Scrollbar(output_frame)
my_listbox3 = tkinter.Listbox(output_frame, height=15, width=60, borderwidth=3, font=my_font, yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar3.set)
# Link scrollbar to listbox
my_scrollbar3.config(command=my_listbox2.yview)
my_listbox3.grid(row=0, column=0)
my_scrollbar3.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=NS)

# Button monitors Layout
remove_item_button3 = tkinter.Button(button_frame, text="Remove Name", borderwidth=5, font=my_font, bg=button_color, command=remove_item3)
save_button3 = tkinter.Button(button_frame, text="Save", borderwidth=5, font=my_font, bg=button_color, command=save_list3)
quit_button3 = tkinter.Button(button_frame, text="Quit", borderwidth=5, font=my_font, bg=button_color, command=root.destroy)
remove_item_button3.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5)
save_button3.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=30)
quit_button3.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=30)

# Define webcams Layout
input_frame = tkinter.Frame(webcams, bg=menu_color)
output_frame = tkinter.Frame(webcams, bg=menu_color)
button_frame = tkinter.Frame(webcams, bg=button_color)
input_frame.pack()
button_frame.pack()

# Input webcams layout
list_entry4 = tkinter.Entry(input_frame, width=41, borderwidth=5, font=my_font)
list_add_button4 = tkinter.Button(input_frame, text="Add A Name", borderwidth=5, font=my_font, bg=button_color, command=add_name4)
output_frame.pack()
list_entry4.grid(row=0, column=0)
list_add_button4.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=2, pady=5, ipadx=5)

# Output webcams layout
my_scrollbar4 = tkinter.Scrollbar(output_frame)
my_listbox4 = tkinter.Listbox(output_frame, height=15, width=60, borderwidth=3, font=my_font, yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar4.set)
# Link scrollbar to listbox
my_scrollbar4.config(command=my_listbox1.yview)
my_listbox4.grid(row=0, column=0)
my_scrollbar4.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=NS)

# Button webcams Layout
remove_item_button1 = tkinter.Button(button_frame, text="Remove Name", borderwidth=5, font=my_font, bg=button_color, command=remove_item4)
save_button4 = tkinter.Button(button_frame, text="Save", borderwidth=5, font=my_font, bg=button_color, command=save_list4)
quit_button4 = tkinter.Button(button_frame, text="Quit", borderwidth=5, font=my_font, bg=button_color, command=root.destroy)
remove_item_button1.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5)
save_button4.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=30)
quit_button4.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=30)

# Define headsets Layout
input_frame = tkinter.Frame(headsets, bg=menu_color)
output_frame = tkinter.Frame(headsets, bg=menu_color)
button_frame = tkinter.Frame(headsets, bg=button_color)
input_frame.pack()
button_frame.pack()

# Input headsets layout
list_entry5 = tkinter.Entry(input_frame, width=41, borderwidth=5, font=my_font)
list_add_button5 = tkinter.Button(input_frame, text="Add A Name", borderwidth=5, font=my_font, bg=button_color, command=add_name5)
output_frame.pack()
list_entry5.grid(row=0, column=0)
list_add_button5.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=2, pady=5, ipadx=5)

# Output headsets layout
my_scrollbar5 = tkinter.Scrollbar(output_frame)
my_listbox5 = tkinter.Listbox(output_frame, height=15, width=60, borderwidth=3, font=my_font, yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar5.set)
# Link scrollbar to listbox
my_scrollbar5.config(command=my_listbox5.yview)
my_listbox5.grid(row=0, column=0)
my_scrollbar5.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=NS)

# Button headsets Layout
remove_item_button5 = tkinter.Button(button_frame, text="Remove Name", borderwidth=5, font=my_font, bg=button_color, command=remove_item5)
save_button5 = tkinter.Button(button_frame, text="Save", borderwidth=5, font=my_font, bg=button_color, command=save_list5)
quit_button5 = tkinter.Button(button_frame, text="Quit", borderwidth=5, font=my_font, bg=button_color, command=root.destroy)
remove_item_button5.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5)
save_button5.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=30)
quit_button5.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=30)

# Define Pucks Layout
input_frame = tkinter.Frame(pucks, bg=menu_color)
output_frame = tkinter.Frame(pucks, bg=menu_color)
button_frame = tkinter.Frame(pucks, bg=button_color)
input_frame.pack()
button_frame.pack()

# Input Docks layout
list_entry6 = tkinter.Entry(input_frame, width=41, borderwidth=5, font=my_font)
list_add_button6 = tkinter.Button(input_frame, text="Add A Name", borderwidth=5, font=my_font, bg=button_color, command=add_name6)
output_frame.pack()
list_entry6.grid(row=0, column=0)
list_add_button6.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=2, pady=5, ipadx=5)

# Output Docks layout
my_scrollbar6 = tkinter.Scrollbar(output_frame)
my_listbox6 = tkinter.Listbox(output_frame, height=15, width=60, borderwidth=3, font=my_font, yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar6.set)
# Link scrollbar to listbox
my_scrollbar6.config(command=my_listbox1.yview)
my_listbox6.grid(row=0, column=0)
my_scrollbar6.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=NS)

# Button Docks Layout
remove_item_button6 = tkinter.Button(button_frame, text="Remove Name", borderwidth=5, font=my_font, bg=button_color, command=remove_item6)
save_button6 = tkinter.Button(button_frame, text="Save", borderwidth=5, font=my_font, bg=button_color, command=save_list6)
quit_button6 = tkinter.Button(button_frame, text="Quit", borderwidth=5, font=my_font, bg=button_color, command=root.destroy)
remove_item_button6.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5)
save_button6.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=30)
quit_button6.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=30)

# Open the previous list if available
open_list1()
open_list2()
open_list3()
open_list4()
open_list5()
open_list6()

# Run the root windows's main loop
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a class to embed the stuff and then you can use that class to create those frames:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class TabFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        self.filepath = kwargs.pop('filepath', None)
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.input_frame = tk.Frame(self, bg=menu_color)
        self.output_frame = tk.Frame(self, bg=menu_color)
        self.button_frame = tk.Frame(self, bg=button_color)

        self.input_frame.pack()
        self.button_frame.pack()
        self.output_frame.pack()

        # Input layout
        self.list_entry = tk.Entry(self.input_frame, width=41, borderwidth=5, font=my_font)
        self.list_add_button = tk.Button(self.input_frame, text="Add A Name", borderwidth=5,
                                         font=my_font, bg=button_color, command=self.add_name)

        self.list_entry.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.list_add_button.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=2, pady=5, ipadx=5)

        # Output layout
        self.my_scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.output_frame)
        self.my_listbox = tk.Listbox(self.output_frame, height=15, width=60, borderwidth=3,
                                     font=my_font, yscrollcommand=self.my_scrollbar.set)
        self.my_scrollbar.config(command=self.my_listbox.yview)

        self.my_listbox.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.my_scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.NS)

        # Button layout
        self.remove_item_button = tk.Button(self.button_frame, text="Remove Name", borderwidth=5,
                                            font=my_font, bg=button_color, command=self.remove_item)
        self.save_button = tk.Button(self.button_frame, text="Save", borderwidth=5, font=my_font,
                                     bg=button_color, command=self.save_list)
        self.quit_button = tk.Button(self.button_frame, text="Quit", borderwidth=5, font=my_font,
                                     bg=button_color, command=root.destroy)

        self.remove_item_button.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5)
        self.save_button.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=30)
        self.quit_button.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=30)

        self.open_list()

    # Define functions
    def add_name(self):
        """Add name to list box"""
        self.my_listbox.insert(tk.END, self.list_entry.get())
        self.list_entry.delete(0, tk.END)

    def remove_item(self):
        """Remove the selected (ANCHOR) item from the listbox"""
        self.my_listbox.delete(tk.ANCHOR)

    def open_list(self):
        if self.filepath:
            """Open list if there is one upon starting"""
            try:
                with open(self.filepath, 'r') as f:
                    for line in f:
                        self.my_listbox.insert(tk.END, line)
            except Exception as ex:
                print(ex)

    def save_list(self):
        if self.filepath:
            """Save file to Text File"""
            with open(self.filepath, 'w') as f:
                # listbox.get() returns a tuple
                list_tuple = self.my_listbox.get(0, tk.END)
                for item in list_tuple:
                # Take proper precautions to include only on \n for formatting purposes
                    if item.endswith("\n"):
                        f.write(item)
                    else:
                        f.write(item + "\n")

# Define fonts and colors
text_color = "#fffacd"
menu_color = "#6c769b"
root_color = "#6c899a"
button_color = "#6c898a"
my_font = ("Times New Roman", 10)

# Define Window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("IT2Go NotePad")
#root.iconbitmap("pad.ico")
root.geometry('500x500')
root.config(bg=root_color)
# root.resizable(0, 0)

it2goNotebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
it2goNotebook.pack(pady=15, fill='both', expand=1)

# Create frame
docks = TabFrame(it2goNotebook, width=500, height=500, bg=root_color, filepath="docklist.txt")
kbcombo = TabFrame(it2goNotebook, width=500, height=500, bg=menu_color)
monitors = TabFrame(it2goNotebook, width=500, height=500, bg=root_color)
webcams = TabFrame(it2goNotebook, width=500, height=500, bg=menu_color)
headsets = TabFrame(it2goNotebook, width=500, height=500, bg=root_color)
pucks = TabFrame(it2goNotebook, width=500, height=500, bg=menu_color)

it2goNotebook.add(docks, text="Docks")
it2goNotebook.add(kbcombo, text="KB Combo")
it2goNotebook.add(monitors, text="Monitors")
it2goNotebook.add(webcams, text="Webcams")
it2goNotebook.add(headsets, text="Headsets")
it2goNotebook.add(pucks, text="Pucks")

# Run the root windows's main loop
root.mainloop()
```